# Link to current page does nothing in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

if I am on the /contact page on my website, if my nav bar has a link to the /contact and  I click it, nothing happens. But if I click any other link that isn't the current url, Angular responds correctly. How do I make it reload the current page when clicking a link to itself in AngularJS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create function which reloads controller and attach that function to view

```
$scope.reloadController = function ({
      $state.go($state.current, {}, { reload: true });
})
```

And atach it to link:

```
<a ng-click="reload()">Contacts</button>
```

Comment: i got it to work with           $scope.reload = function () {
            location.reload();
        }

Answer (score 0):

If the link is to the current page it's actually smart that it doesn't reload. Try using a JavaScript function e.g. reload

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_loc_reload.asp